# Processes Start but do not function when launched with CreateProcessLogonW or similar methods

Tags: c#, .net, c++, winapi

I started using C# to run my applications programmatically and it worked fine under the Administrator account, but as soon as I started to run them with the credentials of a different user "regular user that can run these console applications normally when logged in", they would either function as if they were an infinite loop with no input or output, .net ones would crash, and java would exit instantly.

I need to run these applications under a jailed user with no minimal access to the system beyond the application it is executing, redirect standard input and output to be processed by the host application that is running under a system or administrator account, and ideally hide the console windows of these created processes. So far I have tried this in C# and with various examples of C++...

My Code in C#:

```
// Start the process
currentProcess = new Process();
currentProcess.StartInfo.FileName = AppFile;
currentProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = Args;
// No window and make sure all output is redirected to us
// TODO: Start process as a jailed user
currentProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
currentProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
currentProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = AppPath;
currentProcess.StartInfo.UserName = User.Username;
currentProcess.StartInfo.Password = User.Password;
currentProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
currentProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
currentProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
currentProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
currentProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
currentProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(ExitedHandler);
currentProcess.Start();
```

My code in c++:

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
STARTUPINFO si;

// Set up the start up info struct.
ZeroMemory(&si,sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;// | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.hStdOutput = hChildStdOut;
si.hStdInput  = hChildStdIn;
si.hStdError  = hChildStdErr;
// Use this if you want to hide the child:
//si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
// Note that dwFlags must include STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW if you want to
// use the wShowWindow flags.


// Launch the process that you want to redirect (in this case,
// Child.exe). Make sure Child.exe is in the same directory as
// redirect.c launch redirect from a command line to prevent location
// confusion.
//CreateProcessAsUser(hptoken, 0, cmd, 0, 0, FALSE, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi )

HANDLE hTempUser;
//LogonUserA("tesy","TIM-WORK","test", LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &hTempUser);
//if (hTempUser == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || hTempUser == NULL)
//    DisplayError("LoginUser");
//else if (!DuplicateTokenEx(hTempUser, 0, NULL, SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL::SecurityImpersonation, TOKEN_TYPE::TokenPrimary, &hUserToken))
//    DisplayError("DuplicateUserToken");
//
//// Close the temporary handle to the user
//CloseHandle(hTempUser);

//if (GrantDesktopAccess(hUserToken) != S_OK)
//    DisplayError("GrantDesktop");

//if (!CreateProcessAsUserA(hUserToken,NULL,"C:\\test\\test.exe",NULL,NULL,FALSE,NULL,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi))
//   DisplayError("CreateProcessAsUser");

//CreateProcessWithTokenW(hUserToken, NULL, L"C:\\test\\test.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, L"C:\\test\\", &si, &pi);
CreateProcessWithLogonW(L"tesy", L"TIM-WORK", L"test", LOGON_WITH_PROFILE, L"C:\\test\\test.exe", NULL, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, L"C:\\test\\", &si, &pi);
//if (GetLastError() > 0);
//    DisplayError("CreateProcessWithLogon");

// Set global child process handle to cause threads to exit.
hChildProcess = pi.hProcess;

// Close any unnecessary handles.
if (!CloseHandle(pi.hThread)) DisplayError("CloseHandle");
```

C++ is the best solution for me as I am able to hide the process window, that functionality breaks in .net as soon as username and password are specified.
But in both solutions above I still experience the same issue where the applications do not run correctly.

Also, I have noticed that these processes I am running will run fine when I don't redirect the output. So the issue seems to be with passing the handles for in, out and error across users...

Comment: Well, how are they not running correctly?

Comment: "they would either function as if they were an infinite loop with no input or output, .net ones would crash, and java would exit instantly."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after more testing I found that it is impossible "to my knowledge" to directly route the output and input of an application running under one user to a host application running under an admin type user.

So I solved it with named pipes, I created a basic application in c++ that is intended to be run under a user, this application opens named pipes with a name specified by a command line argument. This "wrapper" application runs the desired application using CreateProcess, as the wrapper is already running under the right user. In, Out and Error streams are redirected by the wrapper to named pipes opened on launch of the wrapper.

My host application can then communicate to the application running under a different user via the pipes opened by the wrapper.

Works good, problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

try looking up ProcessInfo then create the object and assign the properties that you need there.. after that create the actual Process object assign the processInfo object to that Process and create a while loop to check exit code

Comment: This has the same result as using the start info object created by the process itself.
My java processes still exit immediately, .net ones crash, and native ones act like they are in an infinite loop.